# install and run osgEarth on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, openscenegraph, osgearth

I'm trying to compile osgearth library with Qt on Fedora. I install osgEarth by this command:

```
dnf install osgearth-devel
```

By typing `osgearth` in terminal, a black screen with a circle in the middle is displayed. I think that osgEarth is installed and worked correctly.
I want use osgEarth library in Qt, but I can not.
Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After install osgearth, we can use `osgearth viewer file.earth` in terminal to run osgearth. For use osgearth in Qt, we must first add osgearth library to my project. [This simple example](https://github.com/gwaldron/osgearth/blob/master/src/applications/osgearth_map/osgearth_map.cpp) can help you.